# Convert odt to pdf via command line, WITHOUT exporting as pdf form

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

I need to export odt writer file that contains forms to pdf via command line,
but without exporting the odt as pdf form (the same thing as you do in libreoffice when you choose export as PDF and don't select forms).
I know I can do conversion via unoconv or libreoffice command line, but both export odt to
pdf with forms, as far as I have tried. 
So is it possible to convert odt to pdf without exporting the form via command line?
If not via command line, can this be done programatically, like in java or some other language for example?

Comment: there's this [library](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/) written in java.

Answer (score 13):

One possible solution is to use "unoconv" while setting the `--export=ExportFormFields=false` option.

```
unoconv -f pdf --export=ExportFormFields=false mydocument.odt
```

References:

http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.fr/2012/01/unoconv-is-number-one.html
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Tutorials/PDF_export

Comment: In My case, unoconv imply input file is document, and to convert  .ods I need to use
  unoconv -f pdf -d spreadsheet file.ods

Comment: Nice heads up for the `unoconv` tool. However, that is deprecated and instead this one is recommended: https://github.com/unoconv/unoserver